# Psycopg2 is automatically converting tuple to a record

Tags: python, postgresql

Given the following query,

```
SELECT_TOP_DOWNTIMES2: str = """SELECT downtime_cause, 
                                sum(downtime_duration_seconds) total_downtime_duration_seconds
                                FROM dw.dt_causes_by_production_line2(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
                                GROUP BY downtime_cause
                                ORDER BY total_downtime_duration_seconds desc
                                LIMIT 5
                                """
```

where the function is defined as

```
dt_causes_by_production_line2(
_client_id character varying,
_start_timestamp timestamp without time zone, 
_end_timestamp timestamp without time zone,
_is_planned integer, _shifts character varying[], 
_product_skus character varying[],
_production_line_names character varying[])
    returns TABLE(
         production_line_name character varying,
         downtime_cause character varying,
         is_planned integer,
         downtime_duration_seconds double precision
)
```

I am attempting to execute the function via this call

```
pg.select_with_params(SELECT_TOP_DOWNTIMES2, customerid, startdate, enddate, downtimeType, shifts, product_list, production_lines)]
```

where productions lines is defined as a tuple, converted from a comma delimited data set. When I attempt to execute the function, I get the following error:

```
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction: function dw.dt_causes_by_production_line2(unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, record) does not exist
LINE 3:                                 FROM dw.dt_causes_by_product...
```

Oddly, I am able to execute this query directly on the database, but psycops seems to be having some issues. I suspected that the production lines tuple is somehow is being type cast as a record, instead of the intended character varying array. I have modified my query to cast production lines as a character varying array
`dt_causes_by_production_line2(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s::character varying)`
but the error returned is

`psycopg2.errors.CannotCoerce: cannot cast type record to character varying[]`

Is there a way to configure psycopgs2 to stop converting a tuple to a record?

Comment: It seems like receiving a record would be expected behavior. Probably you need to dig inside the record to get to your data.

Comment: I would think so but I have another function that accepts a character varying array, where I pass a tuple and psycops doesn't complain about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this section of `psycopg2` docs [Adaptation](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#adapt-list).

Short version:

1. "Python lists are converted into PostgreSQL ARRAYs:"
2. "Python tuples are converted into a syntax suitable for the SQL IN operator and to represent a composite type".

Make `production_lines` a list. I'm guessing the case that works is also actually a list.